# Laravel Vite: Assets blocked/Mixed Content issues in production environment

Tags: laravel, https, vite

I'm hosting my App on an EC2-instance behind an Elastic Load Balancer which manages my SSL-Certificate. On this EC2-Instance my nginx-configuration is redirecting all http-Requests to https.
I recently switched to Vite which caused me a lot of trouble. When I push my app to the server after calling `npm run build` my assets are blocked. In the browser console I get:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure ...
```

## My Setup:

*vite.config.js*

```
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: 'localhost',
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/assets/sass/app.sass',
            // etc...
        ]),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

Setting "https: true" in the server-block didn't help me.

*.env*

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_URL=https://example.com
ASSET_URL=https://example.com
```

In my blade template I'm using the Vite-directive:

```
@vite('resources/assets/sass/app.sass')
```

I tried the following solutions:

- Setting `$proxies = '*'` in TrustProxies.php, which doesn't have any effect.
- Setting `URL::forceScheme('https');` in AppServiceProvider.php, which will load the assets but lead to a lot of other issues.

Somehow the @vite-directive is not resolving my assets as secure assets. With Laravel Mix I could just call `secure_asset`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you find any solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the TrustedProxies-middleware. However back then I forgot to [register it as global middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#global-middleware).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Laravel with the laravel-vite-plugin,

I solved this in a similar use case by adding:

`ASSET_URL=https://example.com`

You can also add

`APP_URL=https://example.com`

for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

```javascript
import fs from 'fs';

const host = 'example.com';
server: {
    host,
    hmr: {host},
    https: {
        key: fs.readFileSync(`ssl-path`),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(`ssl-cert-path`),
    },
},
```

you should add this to vite.config.js file along with `ASSET_URL` to your `.env` file

Comment: Isn't this supposed to fix mixed content problem in development rather than production?

Comment: After many hours, this is what I needed to do to make sure that vite was feeding from my specific host so I could make use of the specific certificate for that host, in my dev environment. Thank you.